# Reasons/remedies for very slow Glassfish startup due to AMX MBeans?

Tags: java, configuration, proxy, glassfish, startup

I'm wondering if anyone can give me any pointers in relation to the initialization of AMX MBeans on Glassfish. I'm using GF v2.1.1, Java 6 (running as 5) on a Mac.

Whenever I start up GF (which I have to do and redo a LOT), my startup freezes for 90 seconds on this line:

```
ADM1079: Initialization of AMX MBeans started
```

I know that this is due to the proxy server at the company. We are behind a proxy server with NTLM authentication (that causes enough problems in general), and I am running a local Authoxy http proxy instance on localhost to bypass the auth step.

If I switch to a proxy-free network, and remove any system proxy settings, I can start up the server quickly and it doesn't stall here. Unfortunately I can't do this all the time as switching back and forth makes some things unstable. When I'm in the corporate network and have set up the proxy on my system, I always get this delay.

So I know roughly what's causing it, just wondered if anyone can point me in the right direction for speeding this up? It doesn't seem to be timing out, as the server startup continues successfully 90s later. But maybe there's a way of changing AMX MBeans timeout settings, or somehow passing it specific proxy settings which it may not be picking up from the system.

This has been plagueing me and my team for about a year and I can't find much info on configuring this piece of the startup online. So I'm very grateful for any tips or just further info on AMX MBeans you can give me.

```
09-May-2013 11:45:46 com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.launch.ASLauncher buildCommand
INFO: 
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathPrefix=
-Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathSuffix=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/ojdbc5.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.ServerClassPath=
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars.ee=
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars=admin-cli.jar,admin-cli-ee.jar,j2ee-svc.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.excludesList=admin-cli.jar,appserv-upgrade.jar,sun-appserv-ant.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain.ee=
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain=webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath.ee=Does not exist/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,Does not exist/lib/dbstate.jar,Does not exist/lib/hadbm.jar,Does not exist/lib/hadbmgt.jar,/opt/SUNWmfwk/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars.ee=appserv-se.jar,appserv-ee.jar,jesmf-plugin.jar,Does not exist/lib/dbstate.jar,Does not exist/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,jgroups-all.jar,/opt/SUNWmfwk/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars=javaee.jar,/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar,install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,com-sun-commons-launcher.jar,com-sun-commons-logging.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/imqxm.jar,webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar,mail.jar,appserv-jstl.jar,jmxremote_optional.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,activation.jar,appserv-rt.jar,appserv-admin.jar,appserv-cmp.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/updatecenter/lib/updatecenter.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/jbi/lib/jbi.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,dbschema.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.configName=server-config
-Dcom.sun.aas.configRoot=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/config
-Dcom.sun.aas.defaultLogFile=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
-Dcom.sun.aas.domainName=domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceName=server
-Dcom.sun.aas.processLauncher=SE
-Dcom.sun.aas.promptForIdentity=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages=javax.help,javax.portlet
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.taglibs=appserv-jstl.jar,jsf-impl.jar
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.taglisteners=jsf-impl.jar
-Dcom.sun.updatecenter.home=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/updatecenter
-Ddomain.name=domain1
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/endorsed
-Djava.ext.dirs=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/lib/ext:/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/javadb/lib
-Djava.library.path=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib:/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib:/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-Djava.security.policy=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Djmx.invoke.getters=true
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
-client
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-Xms256m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:+LogVMOutput
-XX:LogFile=/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/logs/jvm.log
-cp
/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/jhall.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/SUNWappserver/lib/appserv-launch.jar
com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch
start
Starting Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 ((v2.1 Patch06)(9.1_02 Patch12)) (build b31g-fcs) ...
CORE5076: Using [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Version 1.6.0_45] from [Apple Inc.]
SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
Using MQ RA for Broker lifecycle control
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  Signature Algorithm: MD2withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1000 bits
  modulus: 6144706769222379850430183405655235862870193813433361902309516534729547168229223442088128897090426025874990958624426272027915771330043379079076269082776443120496525109458437435793974957144923190172655546279112796066635455545786300647745888353781002359412766112775410851780140804282673804950495744761467
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Nov 08 16:00:00 PST 1994,
               To: Thu Jan 07 15:59:59 PST 2010]
  Issuer: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    02ad667e 4e45fe5e 576f3c98 195eddc0]
]
  Algorithm: [MD2withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 65 DD 7E E1 B2 EC B0 E2   3A E0 EC 71 46 9A 19 11  e.......:..qF...
0010: B8 D3 C7 A0 B4 03 40 26   02 3E 09 9C E1 12 B3 D1  ......@&.>......
0020: 5A F6 37 A5 B7 61 03 B6   5B 16 69 3B C6 44 08 0C  Z.7..a..[.i;.D..
0030: 88 53 0C 6B 97 49 C7 3E   35 DC 6C B9 BB AA DF 5C  .S.k.I.>5.l....\
0040: BB 3A 2F 93 60 B6 A9 4B   4D F2 20 F7 CD 5F 7F 64  .:/.`..KM. .._.d
0050: 7B 8E DC 00 5C D7 FA 77   CA 39 16 59 6F 0E EA D3  ....\..w.9.Yo...
0060: B5 83 7F 4D 4D 42 56 76   B4 C9 5F 04 F8 38 F8 EB  ...MMBVv.._..8..
0070: D2 5F 75 5F CD 7B FC E5   8E 80 7C FC 50           ._u_........P
];_RequestID=ba54c6aa-d5b5-419d-809a-5db959e52842;|SEC5054: Certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  Signature Algorithm: MD2withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1000 bits
  modulus: 6144706769222379850430183405655235862870193813433361902309516534729547168229223442088128897090426025874990958624426272027915771330043379079076269082776443120496525109458437435793974957144923190172655546279112796066635455545786300647745888353781002359412766112775410851780140804282673804950495744761467
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Nov 08 16:00:00 PST 1994,
               To: Thu Jan 07 15:59:59 PST 2010]
  Issuer: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    02ad667e 4e45fe5e 576f3c98 195eddc0]
]
  Algorithm: [MD2withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 65 DD 7E E1 B2 EC B0 E2   3A E0 EC 71 46 9A 19 11  e.......:..qF...
0010: B8 D3 C7 A0 B4 03 40 26   02 3E 09 9C E1 12 B3 D1  ......@&.>......
0020: 5A F6 37 A5 B7 61 03 B6   5B 16 69 3B C6 44 08 0C  Z.7..a..[.i;.D..
0030: 88 53 0C 6B 97 49 C7 3E   35 DC 6C B9 BB AA DF 5C  .S.k.I.>5.l....\
0040: BB 3A 2F 93 60 B6 A9 4B   4D F2 20 F7 CD 5F 7F 64  .:/.`..KM. .._.d
0050: 7B 8E DC 00 5C D7 FA 77   CA 39 16 59 6F 0E EA D3  ....\..w.9.Yo...
0060: B5 83 7F 4D 4D 42 56 76   B4 C9 5F 04 F8 38 F8 EB  ...MMBVv.._..8..
0070: D2 5F 75 5F CD 7B FC E5   8E 80 7C FC 50           ._u_........P
]
SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
WEB0114: SSO is disabled in virtual server [server]
WEB0114: SSO is disabled in virtual server [__asadmin]
JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [54882]
ADM1079: Initialization of AMX MBeans started
```

It freezes here for about 90 seconds. See the next snippet with timestamps:

```
[#|2013-05-09T11:45:50.394-0700|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|ADM1079: Initialization of AMX MBeans started|#]

[#|2013-05-09T11:47:23.135-0700|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|JMS Service Connection URL is :mq://macbookro.americas.bmw.corp:54881/|#]
```